# How to send buttons to input box?

Tags: javascript, button

I'm trying to send buttons from end result to new input box but have no idea.
I have tried several things.

First

```
for (i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
  var newbutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode("  "+res[i]);
  newbutton.appendChild(t);
  newbutton.style.marginRight = "10px";
  document.body.appendChild(newbutton);
  document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click",ansFunction);
  function ansFunction() {
  document.getElementByid("demo").innerHTML = "answers";
}
}
```

Second

```
for (i=0;i<res.length;i++) {
  var newbutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode("  "+res[i]);
  newbutton.appendChild(t);
  newbutton.style.marginRight = "10px";
  document.body.appendChild(newbutton);
  newbutton.onclick = "ansFunction";
  function ansFunction() {
  document.getElementByid("demo").innerHTML = "answers";
}
}
```

But they dont work.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `res`?

Comment: `function myFunction() {
var str=document.getElementById("input").value;
var res=str.split(" ");

shuffle(res);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = " ";` here it is. I shuffled the input value

Comment: And is `shuffle()` defined? If so, what does it do?

Comment: Yes. `shuffle()` is defined. it shuffles the input value.

Comment: Move your named function `ansFunction` outside of the loop, at least in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

Your variations on the code are failing, but in different ways. The first fails because it adds the `onclick` to the wrong element, and the second fails because it does not properly set the `onclick`. Use the following instead of the text after `document.body.appendChild(newbutton);`:

```
  var ansFunction = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "answers";
  }
  newbutton.addEventListener("click", ansFunction);
}
```

Comment: No. I am going to show the value of the buttons.
I figured out that I cannot put buttons in the input box and I am trying to show the value of the buttons when clicked.